# C# Form Listboxes

Tags: c#, tree, listbox, linked-list

![enter image description here][1]
Hi, I'm trying to display information from two textboxes into two seperate listboxes; One displaying the artist name and one displaying the number of members. Currently, this is what happens when I click the Add Artist button:

As you can see only the artist name shows, and this is because of this piece of code in the artist class:

The is the code in my form class which displays the artist name into listbox1.

I have tried listBox2.Items.Add(Members); and listBox2.Items.Add(artist.Members); in order to try and get it to work, however they both cannot find members. The only way I have found around this is to use the following code, however foreach then comes up with the error message:

![enter image description here][2]
I really don't know where to go from here, any help is appreciated! (I've inserted code from my Artist class and Form class below in case anything helps)

Comment: foreach(Artist artist in ListBoxName.Items). ListBoxName is the name of the list box, it has lots of properties and methods, you need to say which property you need

Comment: Why did you remove all the code? Yes, that was not a good code (!), but it was needed for the question.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want:

```
ArtistTree.InOrderListBox
```

To return a `List<Artist>` instead of a `List<string>`. That way your loop:

```
foreach (Artist artist in ListBoxName)
{ 
     listBox1.Items.Add(artist);
     listBox2.Items.Add(artist.Members);
}
```

Should work.

Right now you are getting an error because ListBoxName is declared as a `List<string>` but you are trying to iterate over it (using foreach) and saying that each item in the List is an Artist, and you've previously said the type of each element in the list is string in your declaration

```
List<string> ListBoxName = new List<string>();
```

Thus, you get a compilation error because you don't have a cast from Artist to string, i.e. you could not do:

```
Artist a = new Artist();
string castMe = (string) a;
```

Calling the ToString() is not the same as casting.

HTH, Nathan

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `ArtistTree.InOrderListBox` method so that it returns (or fills) a list of `Artist`s instead of strings (`Artist.Name`). Also there is no need for the method's parameter to b a `ref` parameter. A normal by-value parameter do the work, because the method doesn't need to change the *argument itself*, rather it changes the *contents* of the argument.

```
List<Artist> artistSorted = new List<Artist>();
ArtistTree.InOrderListBox(artistSorted);

ListBoxNames.DataSource = artistsSorted;
ListBoxNames.DisplayMember = "Name";

ListBoxNames.DataSource = artistsSorted;
ListBoxNames.DisplayMember = "Members";
```

Currently you just have artists' names in the `ListBoxName` list, which is a list of string values. There is no way you can extract the `Members` property from the list of names! You have to change the `ArtistTree.InOrderListBox` method.